# laravel eloquent relation one to one

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel migration like this

`usergroups:`

```php
Schema::create('usergroups', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('id')->primary();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('slug');
});
```

`users:`

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('nik')->primary();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('username');
    $table->string('password');
    $table->string('telp', 15);
    $table->integer('usergroup_id');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->foreign('usergroup_id')->references('id')->on('usergroups')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

`User` model

```php
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Usergroup::class, 'id');
}
```

`Usergroup` model

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'usergroup_id');
}
```

I get blank data with this

```php
$petugas = User::find(1);
return $petugas->group;
```

anyone help me, please...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not a One to One relationship. This is a One to Many relationship. The relation you have build in wrong way according to migration files.

The relation code block should look like this.

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Usergroup::class);
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Some more info:**

In your scenario there might be two possible fact.

1. A user has many groups, but a group is belongs to only one
   user.
2. A group has many users but a user is belongs to only one
   group.

**Fact 1:** In this case the foreign key column should place in groups table. To follow the convention make the foreign column name `user_id` in `groups` table. And the code should look like this

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Usergroup::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

**Fact 2:** In this case the foreign key column should place in users table. To follow the convention make the make the foreign column name `group_id` in `users` table And the relation code should look like this

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Usergroup::class);
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it...
this on user model

```
public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Usergroup::class,'usergroup_id');
    }
```

and this on usergroup model

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class,'usergroup_id');
    }
```